# How do I "swap UI Fragments"?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented an Android Navigation Drawer. It works fine, except that I can't get my fragments to load. What is the code I should enter under `// Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected // For example, swap UI fragments here`?

I have fragments built that correspond with each item in the Navigation Drawer. How do I load up these corresponding fragments?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // set item as selected to persist highlight
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    // close drawer when item is tapped
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
                    // For example, swap UI fragments here

                    return true;
                }
            });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Lookup FragmentTransaction https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: Or edit your question to include where you're trying to load any Fragment, but can't

Comment: My question is not an exact duplicate of the one you linked to. The one you linked to doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The links in the answer do answer the question, though... Also answered in the Android documentation, if you'd take a second to read it over

Comment: As mentioned in the Help Center "*Search, and Research*" is generally expected before posting. Personally, I find the Android documentation a bit dense, and so I point people here too https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments#dynamically

Comment: Regarding your edit. https://guides.codepath.com/android/fragment-navigation-drawer#navigating-between-menu-items